# Map clustering with pie charts to visualise ratios using open layers

Tags: openlayers

I have a map with displaying locations with different statusses (e.g. free, occupied, overstay). As there are a lot of locations, I would like to cluster them. However, I want to provide information about the ratio or amount of locations for each status within each cluster-icon.

a) Is this possible with Open Layers?
b) Are there other libraries, tools or libraries can help me with this?

Example 1:
[image]

Example 2:I found examples using Mapbox.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an ol-ext example using pie charts to display clusters: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/map/map.clustering.html

I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [map.style.chart](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.chart.html) from `ol-ext` might be a good option, you should take a look.

There are several [OL 3rd-party extensions](https://openlayers.org/3rd-party/) that are pretty good, including the one I mention on top.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a suitable solution for myself, so I created my own function for generating diagrams. It is very simple and easily customizable. For your convenience, I have packaged my solution as an open-source project. https://github.com/kossyak/olStyleChart